# Covert Hexademcial String to Byte list in Python

Tags: python, hex, byte

How can I convert a hexadecimal string = `a5acf29e4d11f20b6dee54bf369ee0f8`

To this exactly = **`(bytes([0xa5, 0xac, 0xf2, 0x9e, 0x4d, 0x11, 0xf2, 0x0b, 0x6d, 0xee, 0x54, 0xbf, 0x36, 0x9e, 0xe0, 0xf8])`**

I tried two approaches but they show in a different format.

1. Using bytes.fromhex()

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('a5acf29e4d11f20b6dee54bf369ee0f8')
b'\xa5\xac\xf2\x9eM\x11\xf2\x0bm\xeeT\xbf6\x9e\xe0\xf8'
```

2. Using unhexlify

```
>>> import binascii
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> unhexlify('a5acf29e4d11f20b6dee54bf369ee0f8')
b'\xa5\xac\xf2\x9eM\x11\xf2\x0bm\xeeT\xbf6\x9e\xe0\xf8'
```

However, type of both the formats is same.

```
>>> type(bytes([0xa5, 0xac, 0xf2, 0x9e, 0x4d, 0x11, 0xf2, 0x0b, 0x6d, 0xee, 0x54, 0xbf, 0x36, 0x9e, 0xe0, 0xf8]))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> type(b'\xa5\xac\xf2\x9eM\x11\xf2\x0bm\xeeT\xbf6\x9e\xe0\xf8')
<class 'bytes'>
```

Regardless, I want to display the final format in the byte list format only

`(bytes([0xa5, 0xac, 0xf2, 0x9e, 0x4d, 0x11, 0xf2, 0x0b, 0x6d, 0xee, 0x54, 0xbf, 0x36, 0x9e, 0xe0, 0xf8])`

Could someone please suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try to iterate over `b'\xa5\xac\xf2\x9eM\x11\xf2\x0bm\xeeT\xbf6\x9e\xe0\xf8'` ? You already got what you need.

Comment: I don't think you can do this and preserve the type; `bytes([0xa5, 0xac, 0xf2, 0x9e, 0x4d, 0x11, 0xf2, 0x0b, 0x6d, 0xee, 0x54, 0xbf, 0x36, 0x9e, 0xe0, 0xf8])` is valid input form, but not a valid output form.  Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @snakecharmerb There is an API that I am using, it expects argument in bytes[] format, the input string is a hex string, if I pass bytes.fromhex(str) it will not work, only works when I hardcode it like bytes([0xa5, 0xac....])

Comment: have you tried bytearray.fromhex instead for bytes.fromhex ?

Comment: This is surprising that the `bytes([...])` works while the `b'\x...'` doesn't. [Both are equals](https://www.online-python.com/90GU16Liny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have asked to display in a specific format you can easily do so on cost of your variable datatype

something like this might work

```
bytes_from_hex = bytearray.fromhex('a5acf29e4d11f20b6dee54bf369ee0f8')
print("bytes([",", ".join([hex(b) for b in bytes_from_hex]),"])")

for_disp = "bytes(["+", ".join([hex(b) for b in bytes_from_hex])+"])"
print(for_disp)
print(type(for_disp))
```

If you want byte[] to hit an API then display shouldn't matter, something like this should work

```
bytearray.fromhex('a5acf29e4d11f20b6dee54bf369ee0f8')
```